# Symfony2 Translation using trans_default_domain

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I'd like to translate a part of my twig template which is not in my `trans_default_domain`

For exemple:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
{{ 'test.trans'|trans({}, 'ProjectMainBundle') }}
```

So `test.trans` is translated in ProjectMainBundle but I always have `test.trans` in my text.

**Edit:**

`test.trans` is in `src/Project/MainBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en`

It works everywhere but it doesn't work when I am trying to get my trans with a `trans_default_domain`

Comment: 1) did you clear your cache? 2) where exactly and in what format are your translations for "test.trans" stored - you might want to add this information to the question. syntax-wise this looks okay to me.

Comment: I edit, my trans are in the MainBundle

Comment: hehe my guess was right - see my answer please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are storing the translation in a file called `messages.en.yml` which means according to the [naming conventions for translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-locations-and-naming-conventions) these translations have the domain `messages` and not `ProjectMainBundle`.

Therefore the translator doesn't find a translation if you're trying to use the domain `ProjectMainBundle` and returns the string itself.

> Each message file must be named according to the following path:
>   domain.locale.loader

Your translations should be stored in `@AcmeYourBundle/Resources/translations/<domain>.<locale>.yml` ( or php, xliff, ... ).

Remember to clear your cache after renaming.

Comment: glad to hear - happy coding :-)

Comment: "Remember to clear your cache after renaming." - This is important. Thank you very much.