# Twig trans_default_domain set by dynamic value (i.e. concatenated strings/variables)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

The following example is working as expected following the manual (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates):

```
{% trans_default_domain "app" %}
```

However, I would like to add a dynamic value and/or an variable into "app". I tried the following examples but neither one of them are working:

```
{% set param = 1 %}
{% trans_default_domain "app_"~param %}
```

Or this:

```
{% set param = 1 %}
{% trans_default_domain "app_{param}" %}
```

Or even this does not work:

```
{% set custom_domain = "app" %}
{% trans_default_domain custom_domain %}
```

Or this:

```
{% trans_default_domain "custom_"~"domain" %}
```

I tried to search the net for this problem, but can't find any similar problems. 
It looks like the trans_default_domain is not working with any dynamically generated values. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it usefull ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19282949/2454790

Comment: Does `{% trans_default_domain ('app' ~ param) %}` work?